# How to cast an Object to Arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I need cast an Object to Arraylist:

```
<% Arraylist<Products> mypr = sesion.getAttribute("products");  %>
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <%
                    for (Products xx : mypr) {
                        out.println(xx.toString() + "<br>");
                    }
                %>
```

Comment: I cant use my "for" because is an Object and not an Arraylist

Comment: sesion.getAttribute("products"); <-- this attribute is an object, and I need cast it to arraylist

Comment: Was it an `ArrayList` originally?

Comment: No, an Object from another Servlet

Comment: Show your `setAttribute()` code from that *other* servlet

Comment: ArrayList<Products> product = DBProducts.show(opt);
        sesion.setAttribute("products", product);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's an `ArrayList`, you could cast it (I'd recommend the `List` interface like)

```
List<Products> mypr = (List<Products>) sesion.getAttribute("products");
```

Comment: <% ArrayList<Products> misDatos = ArrayList<Products>(session.getAttribute("products"));  %>

Comment: @SebastianAbiel The parenthesis matter above.